# What are the names of Russian dishes?

Tags: лексикон

What do Russians consider their authentic (not necessarily Russian-original) dishes?

Answer (score 3):

First of all it is `rye-bread (ржаной хлеб)`. People grew wheat and produced flour. Then they cooked `kolatch (калач)`, `oat meal (толокно)`, `pies (пироги пряженые и подовые)`.

Soups have always played an important role in the Russian meal. The traditional staple of soups such as `borscht (борщ)`, `shchi (щи)`, `ukha (уха́)`, `rassolnik (рассо́льник)`, `solyanka (соля́нка)`, `botvinya (ботви́нья)`, `okroshka (окро́шка)`, and `tyurya (тю́ря)` was enlarged in the 18th to 20th centuries by both European and Central Asian staples like clear soups, pureed soups, stews, and many others.

Prior to the distribution of potato (the second half of the XIX century) a `turnip (репа)` served as the main vegetable.

Traditional Russian dressing and dairy product is `smetana (сметана)` (some American people don't call it `"sour cream"` because of other taste and consistence), which is charged with soups and salads. Other Russian dairy product is `cottage cheese (творог)`,  with a help of it we prepare `cottage cheese pancakes (сырники)`.

The best author of numerous culinary books is [William Vasilyevich Pokhlyobkin](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/William_Pokhlyobkin). You can find a lot information about Russian (and many others) cuisine in his books.

Comment: borscht (борщ) was a Ukrainian dish originally, but later became a part of the Russian cuisine.

Comment: творог is typically called "farmer's cheese" at least in the US. I would say that cottage cheese not quite the same as творог.

Comment: That's the case with almost all Russian dishes though... the question specifically asked about non necessarily Russian-original dishes.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think that this is a constructive question, and voted to close, but here are some examples...

- пельмени
- окрошка
- борщ
- щи
- уха
- холоде́ц
- шашлы́к
- блины
- сы́рники
- пирожки

Comment: Why do you use the emphasis only on certain words?

Comment: @Philip: Can you convert your answer to wiki so that everybody can add something? If you press edit, under the text box for editing there is a check box for conversion to wiki.